# how can i select correctly many to many field django

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I need to select 'changes' which related to sku id

I need help with views.py

*models.py*

**Change**

```
class Change (models.Model):
    raw_current = models.ForeignKey(Raw, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='raw_current')
    raw_new = models.ForeignKey(Raw, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='raw_new')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)  # когда была создана заявка

    def __str__(self):
      return self.raw_current.num


    def publish(self):
        self.created_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()
```

**Raw**

```
class Raw (models.Model):
    num = models.CharField(max_length=200)  # артикул сырья
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)  # наименование
    layer = models.CharField(max_length=200)  # название слоя на русском

    def __str__(self):
        return self.num +' ' + self.name
```

**Sku**

```
class Sku (models.Model):
    num = models.CharField(max_length=200)  # артикул готоваой продукции (ГП)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)  # наименование ГП
    raw = models.ManyToManyField(Raw, blank=True, null=True)  # сырье
    weight = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)  # вес
    photo = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True,
                              upload_to="images/")  # фото
    type = models.ForeignKey(ProductsTypes, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.num + ' ' + self.name
```

*views.py*

```
def change(request,sku_id):
    sku = Sku.objects.get(id=sku_id)
    list_change = Change.objects.filter(raw_current = sku.raw)
    return render(request, 'main/change.html', {'sku':sku,'list_change':list_change,'change':change,})
```

*urls.py*

```
   path('change/<sku_id>', views.change, name='change'),
```

## TypeError at /change/1

```
Field 'id' expected a number but got <django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_forward_many_to_many_manager.<locals>.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x10920d9f0>.
```

if in

*views.py*

```
def change(request,sku_id):     
sku = Sku.objects.get(id=sku_id)     
list_change = Change.objects.all()     
return render(request, 'main/change.html',{'sku':sku,'list_change':list_change,'change':change,})
```

then i have the whole list but i need only changes belongs to selected sku

thanks for help

Comment: Try: `raws = sku.raw.all()` to get all the `Raw` objects associated with the `sku = Sku.objects.get(id=sku_id)`.  Then `list_change = Change.objects.filter(raw_current__in=raws)`.

Comment: thanks for your response, was solved list_change = Change.objects.filter(raw_current__in=sku.raw.all()) credits to S Y T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `raw` field in `Sku` model is a `ManyToManyField`, you **CANNOT** do things like this:

```py
list_change = Change.objects.filter(raw_current = sku.raw)
```

A `ManyToManyField` means that you can store not only one `Raw` in the `Sku.raw` field, and you can use `sku.raw.all()` to see all the `Raw`s related to a specific `sku` object.

You can see the official document [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

Thus, if you want to filter all the `Changes` whose `raw_current` are equal to a bunch of `Raw`s belongs to a `sku`,  you can try something like this:

```py
list_change = Change.objects.filter(raw_current__in=sku.raw.all())
```